# how to set dynamic controller name in the partial page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a partial page it is using two View page different controller but there  have same `Edit` Action  method. i need to set controller name dynamically  for particular page in the  run time . how can i do it ?

My partial  page `_SearchProduct` in the shared folder it is working only for `WomanController` action method `Edit`:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Woman", FormMethod.Get))
        {
            <p>
                Find by Product Id : @Html.TextBox("SearchString", ViewBag.CurrentFilter as string)
                <input type="submit" value="Search" />
            </p>
        }
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">


        <span style="color:green">@ViewBag.ProductName </span>
    </div>
    <span style="color:red"> @ViewBag.FindResult </span>
</div>
```

My `WomanController` EDIT page :

```
   @model MKL.Models.WomanProduct

<hr />
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_SearchProduct.cshtml")
<hr />
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">

        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.WomanProductId)

        @if (ViewBag.ProductId != null)
        {

            @Html.Hidden("ProductId", (int)ViewBag.ProductId)
        }

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>


    </div>
}
```

My `ManController` EDIT page :

```
      @model MKL.Models.ManProduct

<hr />
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_SearchProduct.cshtml")
<hr />
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">

        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ManProductProductId)

        @if (ViewBag.ProductId != null)
        {

            @Html.Hidden("ProductId", (int)ViewBag.ProductId)
        }

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>


    </div>
}
```

SO need to dynamically set Partial view Controller name `Man` and `Woman`

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "", FormMethod.Get)){}
```

Comment: Use `Html.Action` to render the partial view and pass the controller name through ViewBag and set it in the `view`. Need more information on when you are calling this partial page, and then we can let you know exact solution..

Comment: @GuruprasadRao please check updated the code

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a model to the partial controller:

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_SearchProduct.cshtml", Model)
```

In `_SearchProduct.cshtml`, `Model` will be of type `WomanProduct` or `ManProduct`, depending on the view that called `Partial`. Then, choose controller depending on the model type:

```
@{
    var ctrl = Model is WomanProduct ? "Woman" : "Man";
}
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", ctrl, FormMethod.Get))
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I would suggest you to use `@Html.Action` to render your `partialview`. Consider below example.

```
@Html.Action("GetSearchPartial", "Controller", new {controller = "Women"}) 
//in the Women Edit View

@Html.Action("GetSearchPartial", "Controller", new {controller = "Man"}) 
//in the Man Edit View
```

Now write an `action` which returns `ParialViewResult`.

```
public PartialViewResult GetSearchPartial(string controller)
{
    ViewBag.Controller=controller;
    return PartialView("_SearchProduct");
}
```

in your `_SearchProduct - PartialView` get the `ViewBag` data and assign it as `controller`.

```
@{
     string controller=ViewBag.Controller;
}
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", controller, FormMethod.Get))
        {
            <p>
                Find by Product Id : @Html.TextBox("SearchString", ViewBag.CurrentFilter as string)
                <input type="submit" value="Search" />
            </p>
        }
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">


        <span style="color:green">@ViewBag.ProductName </span>
    </div>
    <span style="color:red"> @ViewBag.FindResult </span>
</div>
```

Let know if you face any issues

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", @HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString(), FormMethod.Get)){}
```

instead of the actual location of the partial view. so dynamically set `Man` or `Woman` controller name

Comment: please come to this link to help me. I made multiple UIButton in a indexPath in a UICollectionViewCell programmatically. the UIButton does view everything except addTarget function not click..... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46169737/swift-multiple-uibutton-in-a-indexpath-in-a-uicollectionviewcell-programmatical