# Swift: Multiple UIButton in a IndexPath in a UICollectionViewCell programmatically, next addTarget does not click

Tags: ios, uibutton, uicollectionviewcell

I made multiple UIButton in a indexPath in a `UICollectionViewCell` programmatically. now i want to print "clicked add to favourite"  but it is not printing anything after click `UIButton`. the `UIButton` does view everything except `addTarget` function not click.

```
import UIKit

//**UICollectionViewCell**
class DescriptionCell: UICollectionViewCell, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {


    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)


        setupCell()

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }



    lazy var addToCart: UIButton = {

        let btn = UIButton()
        btn.setTitle("Add to favourite", for: .normal)
        btn.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        btn.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)

        btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
        btn.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 8)
        btn.titleLabel?.textAlignment = .right

        // addToCart not click
        btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(addToCartTarget), for: .touchUpInside)

        btn.layer.cornerRadius = 12

        return btn
    }()




    func setupCell() {



        addSubview(addToCart)



        addConstraintsWithFormat("H:|-80-[v0]-80-|", views: addToCart)
             addConstraintsWithFormat("V:|-380-[v0(25)]|", views: addToCart)


    }



    func addToCartTarget() {

        print("you clicked add to favourite")
    }




}
```

[image]

Comment: @AzmalTech There must be issue with button view not addTarget, Try adding simple button first with target only and check whether view is designed properly on screen

Comment: @Abhishek view Design shows properly

Comment: You can use view debugging of Xcode to check dynamic button frame to verify its size

Comment: call    

btn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

Comment: @karthikeyan sorry your coder does not work

Comment: try this btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.addToCartTarget), for:.touchUpInside)
func addToCartTarget(_ sender : UIButton) {
            print("you clicked add to favourite")

}

Comment: @karthikeyan show this error `Expected expression in list of expressions`

Comment: i am using same code only, here working 
Did you add this line btn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154206/discussion-between-azmal-tech-and-karthikeyan).

Comment: I think you should try this: btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.addToCartTarget(_:)), for:.touchUpInside) and then follow @karthikeyan's suggestion

Comment: @3stud1ant3 i got this error `Value of type 'DescriptionCell' has no member 'addToCartTarget'`

Comment: did you change `addToCartTarget` func like this: `func addToCartTarget(_ sender : UIButton) { print("you clicked add to favourite") }` ?

Comment: @3stud1ant3 the error is gone, but UIButton still not print in console after use your code

Comment: @rmaddy sorry! i forget to say "i Added multiple UIButton in a indexPath in a collectionViewCell"

Comment: @3stud1ant3 i am really sorry! i forget to say "i Added multiple UIButton in a indexPath in a collectionViewCell"

Comment: hi bro , how many time DescriptionCell is called

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik sorry i am not realize

Comment: call the method in only one time and check once  the button action is called or not bro

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik so you are going to say that "we can not put UILabel, textView and UIButton in a indexPath together.

Comment: no no for testing purpose try the above code is only one time

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik ok brother! i am going to text wait a moment

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154400/discussion-between-azmal-tech-and-anbu-karthik).

Comment: Please tell me one thing why you didn't add button in CollectionCell from Storyboard?

Comment: Next I want to know few things like is the any GestureRecognizer on CollectionViewViewController or not and next please set few things in your code like set background color of your cell and check button is in the cell boundary or not.

Comment: @UsmanJaved thanks no GestureRecognizer

Comment: Ok then please set background color of Cell and tell me button is in Cell's boundary or not.

Comment: Brother! i have been unable to add pushViewController with this button in collectionViewCell. but added presentViewController by this code 
`self.window?.rootViewController?.present(ViewController(), animated: true, completion: nil)`

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik please Answer this question on this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46639143/swift-json-parse-in-two-pickerview-between-country-and-city?noredirect=1#comment80228030_46639143

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try initializing button with frame like:

```
let btn = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 50, height: 20))
```

Comment: everything is ok of UIButton, just addTarget does not print anything after click button

Comment: I tested your code snippet and its working fine for me.

Comment: sorry! i forget to say "i Added multiple UIButton in a indexPath in a collectionViewCell"

Comment: Brother! i have been unable to add pushViewController with this button in collectionViewCell. but added presentViewController by this code 
`self.window?.rootViewController?.present(ViewController(), animated: true, completion: nil)`

Comment: You can push view controllers to navigation controllers only, `navigationController?.pushViewController(activityTimesTVC, animated: true)`. For this you have to embed yor viewcontroller to navigationcontroller in storyboard. Go to Editor -> Embed In -> Navigation Controller.